# The difference according to the existence of "to be"

Tags: difference

> 1. The painting was declared to be a forgery.

(This sounds like a suspicious declaration or the process of declaration after investigating the painting)

> 2. The painting was declared a forgery.

(This just sounds like a decisive declaration)

What's the difference between them?

I think there's a little difference because of "to be", because to me the 1 seems to convey a suspicious declaration that the painting might be a forgery, but on the other hand, there doesn't seem to be such a suspicious feeling in the 2 sentence but a decisive declaration that the painting is certainly a forgery.

is my thinking correct ?

Comment: There's really no difference between them.  The "to be" in the first sentence is unnecessary as it adds no new information.  The second sentence is somewhat more *decisive*, but since the verb "declare" is already pretty decisive, it's only a small distinction.

Comment: @Andrew Good comment. It would be an even better answer!

Comment: @Tashus  Thanks.  Usually when I comment it's with the intention for someone else to write up a complete answer ... but since no one has jumped at the bait, why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no difference between them. The "to be" in the first sentence is unnecessary as it adds no new information. The second sentence is somewhat more decisive, but since the verb "declare" is already pretty decisive, it's only a small distinction.

Here's a similar example:

> The committee decided the start of the race would be at 9 AM.
>
> The committee decided the race would start at 9 AM.

There is not substantial difference between these sentences -- no hidden meaning, no additional nuance.  The first is more *wordy*, but official statements often like to use more words than necessary.

However this does not mean you can always substitute one for the other, as it depends on the context and the words you use.  For example:

> The forger was declared **to be** in Paris.

You can't say "the forger was *declared* in Paris" because that wouldn't make sense when talking about someone's location.  However you could say:

> The forger was **declared (to be) dead** in Paris.